# Goal: I am trying to implement two different roles on my web application using AWS by using IAM roles to access different web pages (via S3 buckets)

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-iam

*Intro*: I am new to AWS so any help will be greatly appreciated

*Goal*: I am trying to implement two different roles on my web application using AWS by using IAM roles to access different web pages (via S3 buckets)

What I have done:

1 - I have built a front end application hosted on AWS Elastic Beanstalk

2 - The application authenticates using AWS Cognito.

3 - I have integrated AWS Cognito with AWS Cognito Federated Identities to create an identity for each user.

4 - I have created a group called admin in AWS Cognito

5 - I have assigned a new Administrator  IAM role to the admin group

6 - I have added an inline policy for the role to access AWS S3.

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "Stmt1513036814609",
            "Action": "s3:*",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::opaladminpage"
        }
    ]
}
```

7 - I have created a S3bucket

8 - I have uploaded a 1 page Static Website

9 - I have added these S3 policy to my bucket

```
{
  "Id": "Policy1513079053770",
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "Stmt1513079052595",
      "Action": "s3:*",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::opaladminpage",
      "Principal": {
        "AWS": [
          "arn:aws:iam::381145069197:role/SASPortalAdministrator"
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

10 - I have added a url link in my front end application to my 1 page static website
Error message:
I am getting this error message when I click on the link in my application any thought on this?

```
403 Forbidden
•   Code: AccessDenied
•   Message: Access Denied
•   RequestId: 434343543535GFGFGFGF
•   HostId:citytytTTYTYTUTUT
```

Answer (score 0):

```
"Resource": [ 
  "arn:aws:s3:::mybucket",  
  "arn:aws:s3:::mybucket/*" 
]
```

The first resource applies to actions on the bucket, the second applies to actions on objects in the bucket.

Also, don't leave `s3:*` as your action, since that includes everything including deleting objects and even the bucket itself.  You need to identify the actual permissions necessary.